# How to remove all entries (delete data) from root / in Firebase?

Tags: swift, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to reset the database programatically from Swift. I want to achieve the same result as in the Firebase console, clicking the red X on the name of the database (root path)

Comment: You can always set the DBref to null

Comment: For the latest SDK, see https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/save-data#delete_data (the method calls are the same as in @shivamkaushik's answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Firebase API reference](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/) for Objective-C has two methods that seem to be relevant:

- [`Firebase.removeValue`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_removeValue)
- [`Firebase.removeValueWithCompletionBlock:block`](https://www.firebase.com/docs/ios/api/#firebase_removeValueWithCompletionBlock)

The latter allows you to supply a callback to call after the removal has been completed.